# How to call a UIView subclass method from its UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my `HypnosisViewController.m` I have this code for adding a `UIView` subclass, `HypnosisView` to the window. My goal is to set the property `UIColor circleColor` of my `HypnosisView` instance when a `UISegmented` control changes its value.

```
- (void) loadView 
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    HypnosisView *v = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    CGRect segment = CGRectMake(200, 300, 75, 20);
    UISegmentedControl *colors = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithFrame:segment];
    [v addSubview:colors];
    [self setView:v];
}
```

then I would like from here to use an `IBAction` outlet as so, but xcode does not recognize my getter/setter method in my custom class when using this code:

```
- (IBAction)setRingColor:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
        [self.view setCircleColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
    }
}
```

How can I communicate this to my custom `UIView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to downcast it to its derived type.

```
[((HypnosisView *)self.view) setCircleColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: In addition, so long as the view's class will always be the same for all instances of that controller, you may wish to write a type refinement category to redefine the `view` property as having a more specific type. This helps get around the nasty casting.